# Query mysql using ajax, store response and use it to populate a 'social graph'

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on a project where I am trying to use a mysql database which stores the connection between people and places. I am trying to query the database using AJAX and use the response (array) to populate a `'social graph'` using dracula graph librar. I have tried many options and this is just the last thing I have tried. I am open to any other methods for obtaining the same result. This is my Javascript file:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var width = $(document).width() - 20;
    var height = $(document).height() - 60;
    g = new Graph();

    function testAjax(result1) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            global: false,
            dataType: "html",
            url: 'get_chart.php',

            success: function (response) {
                result1.response = response;
            },
        });
    };

    var result1 = { response: null };
    x = testAjax(result1);
    return_first1 = x;

    /* add a simple node */
    g.addNode(return_first1);
```

```html
<?php
    session_start();
 
 //Include database connection details
 require_once('config.php');
 require_once('auth.php');

    $query =("SELECT name_log.person as person,place
              FROM name_log, connection, group
              WHERE connection.name = name_log.name
              AND connection.id = group.id
              AND group.group_code =  'ABC123'
              GROUP BY person
              limit 2");

    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  array_push($data, $row['person']); 
 } 
 echo json_encode($data);  
}
?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? What is the problem?

Comment: when i run the the script it does not generate a node 'return_first1' which suggests that the variable is empty